# How to add 'auto assign public ip' option to level 2 Instance construct

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I know there is a way to add 'auto assign public ip' option to level 1 CfnInstance construct, but is there a way to do that in level 2 Instance construct?

Comment: Do you mean `associatePublicIpAddress` property? This belongs to NetworkInterface definition. Or what property do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [cdk docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html), you can achieve that through the VPC subnet type selection. Below is the cdk code in TypeScript:

```js
const vpc = new aws_ec2.Vpc(this, 'VPC', {
  natGateways: 0,
  subnetConfiguration: [{
    cidrMask: 24,
    name: 'asterisk',
    subnetType: aws_ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
  }]
  // Other configs...
})

const ec2Instance = new aws_ec2.Instance(this, 'Instance', {
  vpc,
  vpcSubnets: {
    // "If you want your instances to have a public IP address 
    // and be directly reachable from the Internet, you must place them
    // in a public subnet."
    subnetType: aws_ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
  },
  // Other configs...
})
```

If you have a lot of subnets, you can use the `subnetFilters` property to narrow them down.

Comment: That's what I did, my ec2 instance launched in the public subnet I selected, but it didn't assign a public address to it.

Comment: @Ichimokuzero, could you check if your public subnets have the 'Auto-assign public IPv4 address' property set to 'Yes'? And double check that you put your instance in the proper subnet. Normally it should assign a public IP address if we place the instance in the public network.

Comment: I faced the same issue as well. Auto-assign public IPv4 address is set to yes. No clue why this happened. The ways that CDK just keeps breaking is mind-boggling!